# How does changing the system time affect SignalR connections

Tags: signalr

I'm not seeing this documented anywhere and google and stackoverflow search doesn't throw up anything. When you have a client on one machine actively connected to a server on another machine, or even the same machine, what is the expected behavior if you change the system time? Seems like there would be something since there are all sorts of timeouts involved.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you seeing issues? Most timeouts aren't looking at system time.

Comment: Yes not sure if it's a causal connection but changing the system datetime and then experiencing a disconnection from the server sometime later

Comment: There were some changes in SignalR and Kestrel depending on the version you are using that changed some DateTime checks to Environment.TickCount64 so changing system time won't affect them anymore.